# issue with image validator rules in laravel 4

Tags: html, image, laravel

I have defined this validating rule for a file(image) in laravel 4 .

```
'image' => 'image|mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png,gif'
```

And this is my html code:

`{{ Form::label('Image of the product') }} {{ Form::file('image') }}`

now , I always get 2 errors while uploading an image even If I chose a png, jpg image

```
The image must be an image.
The image must be a file of type: jpeg, jpg, bmp, png, gif.
```

this is the update action that includes image upload :

```
public function update($id)
  {
    $product = Product::find($id);
    $validator = Validator::make($data = Input::all(), Product::$rules);
    if($validator->fails())
      {
        return Redirect::back()->withErrors($validator)->withInput();
      }
      $old_img = "";
    if(isset($data['image']) and !empty($data['image']))
      {

        $image = Input::file('image');
        $filename = time().'-'.$image->getClientOriginalName();
        Image::make($image->getRealPath())->resize(468, 249)->save('public/img/products/'.$filename);

      $data['image'] = 'img/products/'.$filename;
      $old_img = $product->image;
      }
    $product->update($data);
    File::delete('public/'.$old_img);
    return Redirect::route('admin.products');
  }
```

Comment: Can you provide the HTML just in case you're doing something wrong there. What exact steps make the errors occur?

Comment: {{ Form::label('Image of the product') }}
  {{ Form::file('image') }}

Comment: Have you tried it just using mimes, like so: `'image' => 'mimes:jpeg,jpg,bmp,png,gif'`

Comment: yes i did and i get the second error message

Comment: Can you show us the code of the full controller action?

Comment: OK I just made an edit to hold the update action

Comment: Have you set 'files' => 'true' in the config array for your form?

Comment: thanks @Joe , I totally forgot to set it .. now it's working

Comment: would you like to post it as an answer to approve it

Comment: @thegentletrainer I have added this as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that your form is a multipart one by adding

```
'files' => 'true'
```

to the config array.

Answer (score 0):

first add this to your form tag 
 `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

second in your validation just `'file'=>'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg'`

validate mimes and remove image